# How to configure Zeppelin-env.sh during bootstrapping in EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, aws-cli, apache-zeppelin

I have a script to launch EMR with Spark and Zeppelin through CLI, as well as a bootstrap action to install Anaconda python.

```
aws emr create-cluster --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Spark \
Name=Zeppelin-Sandbox \
...... \
--bootstrap-actions \
'[{"Path":"s3://mybucket/python_config.sh","Name":"Python_Config"},\
{"Path":"s3://mybucket/export_var.sh","Name":"Export_Variables"}]'
```

I tried to configure the zeppelin-env.sh during the bootstrap actions so that the notebooks are stored to a s3 bucket. I had a second script to insert three rows to the file, but it didn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_BUCKET=mybucket' | sudo tee -a /etc/zeppelin/conf.dist/zeppelin-env.sh
echo 'export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_USER=zeppelin' | sudo tee -a /etc/zeppelin/conf.dist/zeppelin-env.sh
echo 'export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_STORAGE=org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.S3NotebookRepo' | sudo tee -a /etc/zeppelin/conf.dist/zeppelin-env.sh
```

Then I tried to add another bootstrap action to install zeppelin through yum instead of the application command "Name=Zeppelin-Sandbox".

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/hadoop/
sudo yum -y install zeppelin
echo 'export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_BUCKET=mybucket' | sudo tee -a /etc/zeppelin/conf.dist/zeppelin-env.sh
echo 'export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_USER=zeppelin' | sudo tee -a /etc/zeppelin/conf.dist/zeppelin-env.sh
echo 'export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_STORAGE=org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.S3NotebookRepo' | sudo tee -a /etc/zeppelin/conf.dist/zeppelin-env.sh
# Start Zeppelin
sudo /usr/lib/zeppelin/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

The launch script then failed with Bootstrapping failed because bootstrap actions returned non-zero error code.

Is there any other way I can insert the configurations to zeppelin-env.sh during the bootstrapping so that it can be automatically setup after the cluster is ready? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap actions run before any applications are installed or configured, so it is not very straightforward to use bootstrap actions for configuring the applications yourself, since directories like /etc/zeppelin/conf won't even exist at the time the bootstrap actions run.

Instead, you should use the Configuration API, as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html

In particular, for this case, you would want to use the "export" sub-classification of the "zeppelin-env" configuration classification.

Comment: Very poorly documented